# Data type of the value stored In string

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

```
String str="32";
```

please let me know how can I know the datatype of the value stored in the object `str`.

I cannot use convert.toint32 as the value in the str is generated during runtime, it can be any primitive type.

Comment: use Int32.TryParse http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I cannot use int32.tryparse cos the value is generated @ runtime so it cannot be only int ,it can be bool or anyother primitive type

Comment: Why can't you? Have a look at the link. If the string you pass is not an "integer" TryParse will return `false`, which means the convertion failed.

Comment: "32" doesn't contain any hint about its assumed datatype. It could be a byte, a short, an int, a long. You could even convert to a floating point value if you want

Comment: @user3883430 Well, looks like you'll have to try parsing the string into different types until you get it right.

Comment: Way too broad. Get a book and learn (a) programming and (b) CSharp basics. You seem to miss any basics that I can think of.

Comment: Ok I agree but if I pass true ,I need to know that data type as bool

Comment: It is nearly impossible to determine the type the string representation of which is contained inside the arbitrary string at least because there are too many types and many of them can have the same string representation. And why do you need to get this information - how will you use it? What is the usage scenario? May be it is completely unnecessary in your program?

Comment: You have a larger problem here of what you are hoping to do with a variable that could be of any type even if you do correctly parse it. You should update your question with your exact problem because there is probably a better specific solution.

Answer (score 4):

make it like that

```
if (int.TryParse(str)) //int
if (bool.TryParse(str)) //bool
if (float.TryParse(str))
if (! str.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) //string
```

but that's really bad idea, you should improve your design.

Answer (score -1):

> please lemme know how can i know the dattype of the value stored in the object str.

var type = typeof(str)

Which will be System.String. The type of the value is a string, always.

> cannot use convert.toint32 as the value in the str is generated during
>   runtime

You needa book about basics because you absolutely can do that dynamically. Convert.ToInt32 works with any variable.

Comment: Tom  as I explained in the question I don't know the value stored in str object during compile time,so how can we use int.tryparse as the value can be any other primitive type??? Apart from int